# Get production sum at timestamp from different production runs

Tags: sql

I currently have a table that show number of counted items at specific times for a specific productionID and its runId (a production can be run in diffrent machines.). See below.

From this data I want the counted for the whole production at the same tmTimestamps. 
If i just group by production id and tmTimestamp i get the correct value untill the last timestamps where i only have values from one ProductionRunID.

EDIT: Example: We only have a value from productionRunID 3080 at 2014-04-08 22:17:38.000, which is 37501. The problem is that we also have produced 19802 from the other productionRunID 3079, but this  line has stopped reporting it because the productionrun is ended there.

Any suggestions?

What i have:

```
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------------+---------+
| ProductionID | ProductionRunID |       tmTimeStamp       | Counted |
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------------+---------+
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 20:38:01.000 |       0 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 20:43:01.000 |       0 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 20:48:02.000 |    2756 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 20:53:02.000 |    8746 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 20:58:03.000 |   15005 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:03:04.000 |   19477 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:04:10.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:09:11.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 21:09:11.000 |       0 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 21:14:11.000 |       0 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:14:11.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 21:19:12.000 |    5216 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:19:12.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 21:24:13.000 |   11480 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:24:13.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:29:14.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 21:29:14.000 |   17791 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 21:34:15.000 |   24065 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:34:15.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:39:16.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 21:39:16.000 |   30356 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 21:43:03.000 |   34881 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:43:03.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:48:04.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 21:48:04.000 |   37501 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 21:50:44.000 |   37501 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:50:44.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:51:54.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 21:51:54.000 |   37501 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 21:56:55.000 |   37501 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 21:56:55.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 22:01:56.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 22:01:56.000 |   37501 |
|       889929 |            3079 | 2014-04-08 22:02:37.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 22:02:37.000 |   37501 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 22:07:37.000 |   37501 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 22:12:37.000 |   37501 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 22:17:38.000 |   37501 |
|       889929 |            3080 | 2014-04-08 22:22:38.000 |   37501 |
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------------+---------+
```

What I want:

```
+--------------+-------------------------+---------+
| ProductionID |       tmTimeStamp       | Counted |
+--------------+-------------------------+---------+
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 20:17:58.000 |       0 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 20:22:59.000 |       0 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 20:27:59.000 |       0 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 20:33:00.000 |       0 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 20:38:01.000 |       0 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 20:43:01.000 |       0 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 20:48:02.000 |    2756 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 20:53:02.000 |    8746 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 20:58:03.000 |   15005 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:03:04.000 |   19477 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:04:10.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:09:11.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:14:11.000 |   19802 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:19:12.000 |   25018 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:24:13.000 |   31282 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:29:14.000 |   37593 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:34:15.000 |   43867 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:39:16.000 |   50158 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:43:03.000 |   54683 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:48:04.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:50:44.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:51:54.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 21:56:55.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:01:56.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:02:37.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:07:37.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:12:37.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:17:38.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:22:38.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:27:39.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:32:39.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:37:40.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:42:41.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:47:42.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:52:43.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:57:44.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 22:59:26.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 23:04:27.000 |   57303 |
|       889929 | 2014-04-08 23:04:47.000 |   57303 |
+--------------+-------------------------+---------+
```

EDIT2: Added example result.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say "i get the correct value untill the last timestamps" but don't say what happens then and why it is not what you want.

Comment: The problem is with the last timestamps i only have values from one machine (productionRunId). So at 2014-04-08 22:01:56.000 i have counted: 37501 + 19802. But later at 2014-04-08 22:17:38.000 i have only 37501. Thus less produced than before.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still very poorly stated which makes it difficult for others to provide help. I have gleaned from your various comments that you want the result to include a sub-total of the `counted` column which is the sum of `counted` from all chronologically prior rows for the same `productionId` and `productionRunId`. The SQL for this would be:

```
select t1.ProductionID, t1.ProductionRunID, t1.tmTimeStamp, t1.counted, 
(
  select sum(counted)
  from prod as t2 
  where t1.ProductionID = t2.ProductionID
  and   t1.ProductionRunID = t2.ProductionRunID
  and   t1.tmTimeStamp >= t2.tmTimeStamp
) as sub_total
from prod as t1
order by 1, 2, 3
;
```

You have not stated which database you are using, and more complex SQL usually gets implementation-specific (or is simpler with a particular database's features). I assumed mySQL.

Here is a fiddle to illustrate it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f794/7

Note that in your original question you stated that you wanted to `group by` the timestamp - which was wrong and lead readers to misunderstand the problem. Please try to be clearer next time and give an example of the desired result and the table structure.

Comment: Thanks for trying to understand, but your result is not what i wanted. I just want the counted for the whole production, not for each line as it is now. I added the desired result to the first post. So grouping would give the correct result, if i had values for each productionRunId (machine) at every timestamp.

Comment: OK, the sample expected result helps (though it doesn't match your input). Did you try removing the `ProductionRunID` from the query like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f794/8

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
select
    ProductionId
    ,ProductionRunId
    ,tmTimeStamp
    ,sum(Counted)
from
    ProdTable-or-whatever-it-is-called 
group by 
    ProductionId
    ,ProductionRunId
    ,tmTimeStamp
order by 
    ProductionId
    ,ProductionRunId
,tmTimeStamp
```

Comment: No, this will not give correct total counted for the timestamps were we only have values from one machine. Example: We only have a value from productionRunID 3080 at 2014-04-08 22:17:38.000, which is 37501. The problem is that we also have produced 19802 from the other productionRunID 3079, but that line has stopped reporting it because something else is running there now.

Comment: It looks like you want to create a matrix (based on ProductionId, ProductionRunId, tmTimeStamp) and then join them against the sum of the Counted.  Correct?

Comment: At each tmTimestamp i would like the sum of each ProductionRunID's  counted where tmTimestamp is the largest timestamp that is less or equal to the tmTimestamp. So at 22:17:38.000 i would like to get 37501+19802. (I want to get the total number of produced items)